# How can I remove duplicates from each item in jsrender template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, jsrender

I am trying to remove duplicate file from each div in jsrender but not able to do it correctly as all the duplicates get removed.

```
$('.media-holder').each(function () {
  $('.media-item').each(function () {
    $('.media-item:contains("' + $(this).text() + `enter code here`'"):gt(0)').remove();
  });
});
```

**Current output:**

```
**Files part 1**
abc file
def file
abc file
**Files part 2**
abc file
def file
abc file
def file
ghi file
```

**Desired Output:**

```
**Files part 1**
abc file
def file
**Files part 2**
abc file
def file
ghi file
```

Comment: Firstly the JS quotes seem broken, and the 'enter code here' isn't helping make the issue clear. Secondly, please add all relevant HTML to the question so we can replicate the problem

Comment: <div class="audio">
{{for AgendaPaperAssets}}
{{if AudioSrc || AudioSrc2}}
 <ul>
  {{if AudioSrc}}
  <li><a href="{{:AudioSrc}}" class="media-item" id="ado-item" target="_blank"><img src="/images/icons/doc-mp3.svg" alt=""> {{:AudioMediaItemFile.Description}}</a></li>
  {{/if}}
  {{if Audio2Src}}
  <li><a href="{{:Audio2Src}}" class="media-item" id="ado-item2" target="_blank"><img src="/images/icons/doc-mp3.svg" alt="">{{:Audio2MediaItemFile.Description}}</a></li>
  {{/if}}
 </ul>
{{/if}}

{{/for}}
</div>

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under the question as code in comments is unreadable. It would also be more helpful to see the *actual* HTML output, not the template, as the template itself is not relevant to the problem

Comment: yes multiple media-items or I can change the class to audio(multiple audio).

Comment: In the above html code, I am trying not to duplicate the <li> items for each item of for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `media-holder` as a [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context)

```js
$('.media-holder').each(function(i, holder) {
  $('.media-item').each(function() {
    $('.media-item:contains("' + $(this).text() + '"):gt(0)', holder).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="media-holder">
  <div class="media-item">abc file</div>
  <div class="media-item">def file</div>
  <div class="media-item">abc file</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="media-holder">
  <div class="media-item">abc file</div>
  <div class="media-item">def file</div>
  <div class="media-item">abc file</div>
  <div class="media-item">def file</div>
  <div class="media-item">ghi file</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!! This worked for me :)) Thank you. Can you explain me what i and holder means in the javascript function here?

Comment: they are just variables where `i` is index and `holder` (media-holder) is HTML element. check [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for more info